# JavaFX HTMLEditor ignores enter on red hat

Tags: javafx, redhat, html-editor

I am trying to figure out how to get around the enter key being ignored by the JavaFX HTMLEditor.

OS:

```
 Redhat Enterprise Linux Workstation 7.5
```

Java:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

The enter key doesn't work, but Control-M does. I'm trying to get around this by intercepting all the enter key presses, and then replacing them with carriage returns. However, when I programatically fire a carriage return key event, nothing happens.

My test code is:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HTMLEditorTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("HTMLEditor Test");
        final HTMLEditor htmlEditor = new HTMLEditor();
        Scene scene = new Scene(htmlEditor, 800, 800);

        htmlEditor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
        {
            //System.out.println(htmlEditor.getHtmlText());
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.M && event.isControlDown())
            {
                 System.out.println("\nSource: " + event.getSource().getClass().getName());
                 System.out.println("Target: " + event.getTarget().getClass().getName());
                 System.out.println("Character: '" + event.getCharacter().hashCode() + "'");
                 System.out.println("Text: '" + event.getText() + "'");
                 System.out.println("Text: '" + event.getText().hashCode() + "'");
                 System.out.println("Shift Down: " + event.isShiftDown());
                 System.out.println("Control Down: " + event.isControlDown());
                 System.out.println("Meta Down: " + event.isMetaDown());
                 System.out.println("Alt Down: " + event.isAltDown() + "\n");
             }

             if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
             {
                 KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, "", "\r", KeyCode.M, false, true, false, false);
                 KeyEvent.fireEvent(event.getTarget(), ke);
             }

         });

         stage.setScene(scene);
         stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you run this and type 'Control-M', `<p><br></p>` is inserted into the htmlText.
If you type 'Enter', nothing happens even though I am firing a key event that should trigger the same reaction as 'Control-M'.
To investigate this I printed out all the info I could on the KeyEvent generated by 'Control-M' and the KeyEvent that I fired. As far as I can tell, they are identical.

When I type 'Enter', intercept the 'Enter' KeyEvent and then fire a new KeyEvent:

```
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"></body></html>

Source: javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor
Target: javafx.scene.web.WebView
Character: '0'
Text: '
'
Text: '13'
Shift Down: false
Control Down: true
Meta Down: false
Alt Down: false
```

When I type 'Control-M':

```
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><p><br></p></body></html>

Source: javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor
Target: javafx.scene.web.WebView
Character: '0'
Text: '
'
Text: '13'
Shift Down: false
Control Down: true
Meta Down: false
Alt Down: false
```

They seem identical, but only the KeyEvent generated by actually typing 'Control-M' does anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, getting the 'Enter' key to actually insert a new line. It seems as if a private method in the HTMLEditorSkin isn't getting properly invoked. Be aware, this isn't a great solution and I would consider it an ugly hack.

```
htmlEditor.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
        {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
            {
                event.consume();

                final HTMLEditorSkin skin = (HTMLEditorSkin) htmlEditor.getSkin();

                    try
                    {
                        // Invoke the private executeCommand(Command.INSERT_NEW_LINE.getCommand(), null);
                        final Method method = skin.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("executeCommand", String.class, String.class);
                        method.setAccessible(true);
                        method.invoke(skin, Command.INSERT_NEW_LINE.getCommand(), null);
                    }
                    catch (Throwable ex)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot hack around ENTER", ex);
                    }
            }
        });
```